# How to add a onmouseover Attribute method in lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

We are using lightning datatable for inline editing and i want that the data table records  should be seen through popover .
I am using below code :- i tried to add onmouseover method but its not working . please suggest the alternative method, for that .

```
 doInit : function( component, event, helper ) {
        component.set( 'v.columns', [
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'autonumber' ,editable: false},
            {label: 'Position', fieldName:'linkURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName: 'Service__c'}, target:'_blank'}, onmouseover:'{hoverOpenPop}'},
            {label: 'Annual', fieldName: 'Annual__c', type: 'currency' ,editable: false} 
        ]);
        helper.doInitHelper(component);
    },
```

Comment: i posted similar kind of question few months back :https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294589/how-to-display-tooltip-on-lightning-data-table-cells.